# Drawer layout menu extra icon add title right side from xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Inside drawer menu I have icon and title (for clear understand check image). May i do this from xml or i need to do customize that. I already make that customization but i am searching more easiest way.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_category"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Categories" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Invite Friends" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_help"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Help" />
    </group>


</menu>
```

Comment: create group inside item in your menu.xml

Comment: Use expandable listview for this case.

Comment: Mohamed mohaideen Can you give example to create Group and design such like above.

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-sidebar-navigation-drawer-with-icons/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this set Custom View to your menu item like this

```
 TextView textView = new TextView(this);
 textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0);
 navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setActionView(textView);
```

Comment: Its working. but image not showing parallel. it shows above of the title

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0,20,0,0);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

I use this but not working why

Comment: Thanks for you help I accept your answer. 
but  textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp, 0); help to solve. just set the image in left.

Comment: @Tariqul happy to help you my friend